# In R, building S4 class but get Error in validityMethod(as(object, superClass))

Tags: r, inheritance, r-s4

I created three S4 classes with their own constructors. Class A, inherits from data.frame and has one additional slot named 'color'. Class B inherits from A and only add one more variable to the inherited data frame. Class C inherits from B and also expand the inherited data frame by one variable. Here is an example:

```
.A <- setClass("A",
               representation(color = "character"),
               prototype(color = NA_character_),
               contains = "data.frame",
               validity = function(object) {
                 errors <- character()
                 if (length(object@color) != 1) {
                   msg <- paste("color must be of length = 1")
                   errors <- c(errors, msg)
                 }
                 if (length(errors) == 0) TRUE else errors
               }
               )

A <- function(x = NA_real_, 
              y = NA_real_, 
              color = NA_character_, ...) {
  data <- data.frame("x" = x, "y" = y, ...)
  .A(data, color = color)
  } 

.B <- setClass("B",
               contains = "A")

B <- function(x = NA_real_, 
              y = NA_real_, 
              z = NA_real_,
              color = NA_character_, ...) {
  .B(A(x = x, y = y, z = z, color = color, ...))
}

.C <- setClass("C",
               contains = "B")

C <- function(x = NA_real_, 
              y = NA_real_, 
              z = NA_real_,
              w = NA_real_,
              color = NA_character_, ...) {
  .C(B(x = x, y = y, z = z, w = w, color = color, ...))
}
```

However, I must be doing something wrong because validObject(.A()) and validObject(.B()) both return TRUE while validObject(.C()) failed

```
validObject(.A())
[1] TRUE
validObject(.B())
[1] TRUE
validObject(.C())
Error in validityMethod(as(object, superClass)) : 
  no slot of name "color" for this object of class "data.frame"
```

If I delete the validity constrains from my representation of class A then validObject(.C()) returns TRUE.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for reading!